# PHPMailer in combination with Gmail smtp sending mail twice

Tags: phpmailer

I have come across some weird behaviour in PHPMailer. I am using my gmail account for the SMTP settings. But every time PHP sends an e-mail(in this case, it's for resetting a password), I receive the same e-mail too. Except for when the password reset is requested for my gmail account.

Here is the code;

```
//set email settings
            $mail       =   new PHPMailer;
            $mail->IsSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
            $mail->Host = 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com';  // Specify main and backup server
            $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
            $mail->Port = 465;
            $mail->Username = 'mymail@gmail.com';                            // SMTP username
            $mail->Password = 'mypassword';                           // SMTP password

            $mail->From = 'noreply@bla.com';
            $mail->FromName = 'Bla';
            $mail->AddAddress($email);               // Name is optional
            $mail->IsHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML

            $mail->Subject  = 'Bla registration';
            $mail->Body ="
            <html>
                <header><title>Welcome to Bla</title></header>
                <body>
                <p>Hello,</p>
                <p>Welcome to Bla. Thank you for registering an account. Before you can start inventing music, please activate your account</p>
                <p><a href='http://www.bla.com/register/activate.php?activation=$activationcode&email=$email'>  http://www.Bla.com/register/activate.php?activation=$activationcode&email=$email</a></p>
                See you soon on Bla!
                </body>
            </html>";
$mail->Send();
```

There is no error or something like that. The e-mail is actually send, and received. Only problem is that I receive as well because the e-mail address in Username is my e-mail address. Does anyone know why this happens?

Answer (score 1):

Add ClearAddresses like this->

```
$mail->Send();
$mail->ClearAddresses();
```

And solved.

Greetens

Answer (score 0):

Try to change

```
$mailer->isSMTP();
```

to

```
$mailer->Mailer = 'smtp';
```